# Can't start IntelliJ IDEA after upgrade

Tags: intellij-idea

I've upgraded to the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA and now it doesn't start. Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.connect()V from class com.zeroturnaround.optimizer.plugin.functions.platform.caches.CacheApi 
at com.zeroturnaround.optimizer.plugin.functions.platform.caches.CacheApi.cachesLastCleanedVFS(CacheApi.java:34) 
at com.zeroturnaround.optimizer.plugin.functions.platform.caches.CacheApi.cacheLastCleaned(CacheApi.java:17) 
at com.zeroturnaround.optimizer.plugin.activities.CleanCacheActivity.doInitialize(CleanCacheActivity.java:22) 
at com.zeroturnaround.optimizer.plugin.activities.AbstractActivity.initialize(AbstractActivity.java:29) 
at com.zeroturnaround.optimizer.plugin.state.model.ApplicationStateInitializer.initialize(ApplicationStateInitializer.java:20) 
at com.zeroturnaround.optimizer.plugin.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:62) 
at com.zeroturnaround.optimizer.plugin.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:22) 
at com.zeroturnaround.optimizer.plugin.Bootstrap$1.run(Bootstrap.java:37) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: How did you find stacktrace? I just double click on icon and it doesn't work, so I would like to get what you did.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by Optimizer [Zeroturnaround](https://zeroturnaround.com/) plugin. To solve the issue, please remove the plugin manually from [IDE plugins folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519).

Comment: For Mac user you can find the failing plugin here: ~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea{VERSION}/ft-intellij-optimizer . Just delete this directory